# Compulsory reading, is it right?

Tags: synonyms

Is compulsory reading an appropriate name for books that you have to read at middle and elementary school? I read here

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3715/differences-between-mandatory-and-compulsory

that compulsory is more often used in contexts of education,  business and employment, while mandatory is mainly used in legal contexts, so, by this logic, compulsory reading should be right, but at the above page there also are  commenters who argue that mandatory means the attributee is required to be done but not enforced, while compulsory implies that if one does not do the required thing then some external force will compel him.

So, by this second logic, I think mandatory reading would be a better way of calling books that one has to read in school since not doing it won't incur serious consequences (other than maybe receiving bad marks)

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. Nevertheless, I grew up hearing *compulsory reading*. That said, you are *compelled* to do something *compulsory* and it is *mandated* that you do something *mandatory* - you don't hear of many mandates in school, but you do in a legal context.

Comment: Two other terms that often come up in U.S. English discussions of reading lists and the like are "assigned reading" (books that students are supposed to read for a class) and "required reading" (outside a scholastic context, books that [in someone's opinion] one must read in order to have a thorough and up-to-date command of a particular subject area).

Comment: In the US I've always heard "required reading" for stuff that a student is, well, required to read.